# counting after and before change in value, within groups, generating new variables for each unique shift

Tags: r, count, data-manipulation

I am working to count occurrences of unique values within my groups, `id`. I'm looking at `TF`. When `TF` changes I want to count both forward and backwards from that point. This counting should be stored in a new variable `PM#`, so that `PM#` holds both plus and minus *to each unique shift* in  `TF`. From what I've gathered I need to use `rle`, but I am kinda stuck.

I made this working example to illustrate my issue.

I have this data

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), TF = c(NA, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 0L, 
0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), .Names = c("id", "TF"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))
```

This is the kinda data I am seeing

```
df[c(1:12,19:30),]
#>    id TF
#> 1   0 NA
#> 2   0  0
#> 3   0 NA
#> 4   0  0
#> 5   0  0
#> 6   0  1
#> 7   0  1
#> 8   0  1
#> 9   0 NA
#> 10  0  0
#> 11  0  0
#> 12  1 NA
#> 19  1 NA
#> 20  7 NA
#> 21  7  0
#> 22  7  0
#> 23  7  1
#> 24  7  0
#> 25  7  0
#> 26  7  1
#> 27  7  0
#> 28  7  1
#> 29  7  1
#> 30  7  1
```

I've started meddling with `ave`, `cumsum` and with `rle`, but haven't solved it this way yet.

```
df$PM01 <- with(df, ifelse(is.na(TF), NA, 1))
df$PM01 <- with(df, ave(PM01, TF, id, FUN=cumsum))

with(df, tapply(TF, rep(rle(id)[[2]], rle(id)[[1]]), count))
```

This is what I am trying to obtain,

```
dfa <- structure(list(id = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L), TF = c(NA, 0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, 0L, 
0L, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), PM1 = c(NA, -3L, NA, -2L, -1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, -3L, -2L, -1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, NA, NA, -2L, -1L, 1L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), PM2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -3L, 
-2L, -1L, NA, 1L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, -1L, 1L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), PM3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, -2L, -1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA), PM4 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -1L, 1L, NA, NA, NA), PM5 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -1L, 1L, 2L, 3L)), .Names = c("id", 
"TF", "PM1", "PM2", "PM3", "PM4", "PM5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-30L))

dfa[c(1:12,19:30),]
#>    id TF PM1 PM2 PM3 PM4 PM5
#> 1   0 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#> 2   0  0  -3  NA  NA  NA  NA
#> 3   0 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#> 4   0  0  -2  NA  NA  NA  NA
#> 5   0  0  -1  NA  NA  NA  NA
#> 6   0  1   1  -3  NA  NA  NA
#> 7   0  1   2  -2  NA  NA  NA
#> 8   0  1   3  -1  NA  NA  NA
#> 9   0 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#> 10  0  0  NA   1  NA  NA  NA
#> 11  0  0  NA   2  NA  NA  NA
#> 12  1 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#> 19  1 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#> 20  7 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#> 21  7  0  -2  NA  NA  NA  NA
#> 22  7  0  -1  NA  NA  NA  NA
#> 23  7  1   1  -1  NA  NA  NA
#> 24  7  0  NA   1  -2  NA  NA
#> 25  7  0  NA   2  -1  NA  NA
#> 26  7  1  NA  NA   1  -1  NA
#> 27  7  0  NA  NA  NA   1  -1
#> 28  7  1  NA  NA  NA  NA   1
#> 29  7  1  NA  NA  NA  NA   2
#> 30  7  1  NA  NA  NA  NA   3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was really a tricky one, and I'm sure the code can be further improved. However, I was able to reproduce your expected result.  Please, try this approach with your production data. If OK, I will add an explanation later.

```
library(data.table)

tmp <- setDT(df)[, rn := .I][!is.na(TF)][, rl := rleid(TF), by = id][
  , c("up", "dn") := .(seq_len(.N), -rev(seq_len(.N))), by = .(id, rl)][]

res <- tmp[tmp[, seq_len(max(rl) - 1L), by = .(id)], on = .(id), allow.cartesian = TRUE][
  rl == V1, PM := dn][rl == V1 + 1L, PM := up][
    , dcast(.SD, id + TF + rn ~ paste0("PM", V1), value.var = "PM")][
      df, on = .(rn, id, TF)][, -"rn"]
res
```

> ```
>     id TF PM1 PM2 PM3 PM4 PM5
>  1:  0 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
>  2:  0  0  -3  NA  NA  NA  NA
>  3:  0 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
>  4:  0  0  -2  NA  NA  NA  NA
>  5:  0  0  -1  NA  NA  NA  NA
>  6:  0  1   1  -3  NA  NA  NA
>  7:  0  1   2  -2  NA  NA  NA
>  8:  0  1   3  -1  NA  NA  NA
>  9:  0 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
> 10:  0  0  NA   1  NA  NA  NA
> 11:  0  0  NA   2  NA  NA  NA
> 12:  1 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
> 13:  1  0  -3  NA  NA  NA  NA
> 14:  1  0  -2  NA  NA  NA  NA
> 15:  1  0  -1  NA  NA  NA  NA
> 16:  1  1   1  NA  NA  NA  NA
> 17:  1  1   2  NA  NA  NA  NA
> 18:  1  1   3  NA  NA  NA  NA
> 19:  1 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
> 20:  7 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
> 21:  7  0  -2  NA  NA  NA  NA
> 22:  7  0  -1  NA  NA  NA  NA
> 23:  7  1   1  -1  NA  NA  NA
> 24:  7  0  NA   1  -2  NA  NA
> 25:  7  0  NA   2  -1  NA  NA
> 26:  7  1  NA  NA   1  -1  NA
> 27:  7  0  NA  NA  NA   1  -1
> 28:  7  1  NA  NA  NA  NA   1
> 29:  7  1  NA  NA  NA  NA   2
> 30:  7  1  NA  NA  NA  NA   3
>     id TF PM1 PM2 PM3 PM4 PM5
> ```

```
# verify results are identical
identical(res, dfa)
```

> ```
> [1] TRUE
> ```

In case of more than 9 changes per group `paste0("PM", V1)` should be replaced by `sprintf("PM%02d",V1)` in the call to `dcast()` to ensure the `PM` columns are ordered properly.

#### Explanation

```
tmp <- 
  # coerce to data.table
  setDT(df)[
    # create row id column (required for final join to get NA rows back in)
    , rn := .I][
      # ignore NA rows 
      !is.na(TF)][
        # number streaks of unique values within each group
        , rl := rleid(TF), by = id][
          # create ascending and descending counts for each streak
          # this is done once to avoid repeatedly creation of counts for each PM 
          # (slight performance gain)
          , c("up", "dn") := .(seq_len(.N), -rev(seq_len(.N))), by = .(id, rl)]


tmp[]
```

> ```
>     id TF rn rl up dn
>  1:  0  0  2  1  1 -3
>  2:  0  0  4  1  2 -2
>  3:  0  0  5  1  3 -1
>  4:  0  1  6  2  1 -3
>  5:  0  1  7  2  2 -2
>  6:  0  1  8  2  3 -1
>  7:  0  0 10  3  1 -2
>  8:  0  0 11  3  2 -1
>  9:  1  0 13  1  1 -3
> 10:  1  0 14  1  2 -2
> 11:  1  0 15  1  3 -1
> 12:  1  1 16  2  1 -3
> 13:  1  1 17  2  2 -2
> 14:  1  1 18  2  3 -1
> 15:  7  0 21  1  1 -2
> 16:  7  0 22  1  2 -1
> 17:  7  1 23  2  1 -1
> 18:  7  0 24  3  1 -2
> 19:  7  0 25  3  2 -1
> 20:  7  1 26  4  1 -1
> 21:  7  0 27  5  1 -1
> 22:  7  1 28  6  1 -3
> 23:  7  1 29  6  2 -2
> 24:  7  1 30  6  3 -1
>     id TF rn rl up dn
> ```

For the next step, we need the count of changes `V1` within each group

```
tmp[, seq_len(max(rl) - 1L), by = .(id)]
```

> ```
>    id V1
> 1:  0  1
> 2:  0  2
> 3:  1  1
> 4:  7  1
> 5:  7  2
> 6:  7  3
> 7:  7  4
> 8:  7  5
> ```

Now, we create a "cartesian join" of all possible changes with the rows of each group:

```
# right join with count of changes within each group
tmp[tmp[, seq_len(max(rl) - 1L), by = .(id)], on = .(id), allow.cartesian = TRUE][
  # copy descending counts to rows before the switch
  rl == V1, PM := dn][
    # copy ascending counts to rows after the switch
    rl == V1 + 1L, PM := up][]
```

> ```
>     id TF rn rl up dn V1 PM
>  1:  0  0  2  1  1 -3  1 -3
>  2:  0  0  4  1  2 -2  1 -2
>  3:  0  0  5  1  3 -1  1 -1
>  4:  0  1  6  2  1 -3  1  1
>  5:  0  1  7  2  2 -2  1  2
>  6:  0  1  8  2  3 -1  1  3
>  7:  0  0 10  3  1 -2  1 NA
>  8:  0  0 11  3  2 -1  1 NA
>  9:  0  0  2  1  1 -3  2 NA
> 10:  0  0  4  1  2 -2  2 NA
> 11:  0  0  5  1  3 -1  2 NA
> 12:  0  1  6  2  1 -3  2 -3
> 13:  0  1  7  2  2 -2  2 -2
> 14:  0  1  8  2  3 -1  2 -1
> 15:  0  0 10  3  1 -2  2  1
> 16:  0  0 11  3  2 -1  2  2
> 17:  1  0 13  1  1 -3  1 -3
> 18:  1  0 14  1  2 -2  1 -2
> 19:  1  0 15  1  3 -1  1 -1
> 20:  1  1 16  2  1 -3  1  1
> 21:  1  1 17  2  2 -2  1  2
> 22:  1  1 18  2  3 -1  1  3
> 23:  7  0 21  1  1 -2  1 -2
> 24:  7  0 22  1  2 -1  1 -1
> 25:  7  1 23  2  1 -1  1  1
> 26:  7  0 24  3  1 -2  1 NA
> 27:  7  0 25  3  2 -1  1 NA
> 28:  7  1 26  4  1 -1  1 NA
> 29:  7  0 27  5  1 -1  1 NA
> 30:  7  1 28  6  1 -3  1 NA
> 31:  7  1 29  6  2 -2  1 NA
> 32:  7  1 30  6  3 -1  1 NA
> 33:  7  0 21  1  1 -2  2 NA
> 34:  7  0 22  1  2 -1  2 NA
> 35:  7  1 23  2  1 -1  2 -1
> 36:  7  0 24  3  1 -2  2  1
> 37:  7  0 25  3  2 -1  2  2
> 38:  7  1 26  4  1 -1  2 NA
> 39:  7  0 27  5  1 -1  2 NA
> 40:  7  1 28  6  1 -3  2 NA
> 41:  7  1 29  6  2 -2  2 NA
> 42:  7  1 30  6  3 -1  2 NA
> 43:  7  0 21  1  1 -2  3 NA
> 44:  7  0 22  1  2 -1  3 NA
> 45:  7  1 23  2  1 -1  3 NA
> 46:  7  0 24  3  1 -2  3 -2
> 47:  7  0 25  3  2 -1  3 -1
> 48:  7  1 26  4  1 -1  3  1
> 49:  7  0 27  5  1 -1  3 NA
> 50:  7  1 28  6  1 -3  3 NA
> 51:  7  1 29  6  2 -2  3 NA
> 52:  7  1 30  6  3 -1  3 NA
> 53:  7  0 21  1  1 -2  4 NA
> 54:  7  0 22  1  2 -1  4 NA
> 55:  7  1 23  2  1 -1  4 NA
> 56:  7  0 24  3  1 -2  4 NA
> 57:  7  0 25  3  2 -1  4 NA
> 58:  7  1 26  4  1 -1  4 -1
> 59:  7  0 27  5  1 -1  4  1
> 60:  7  1 28  6  1 -3  4 NA
> 61:  7  1 29  6  2 -2  4 NA
> 62:  7  1 30  6  3 -1  4 NA
> 63:  7  0 21  1  1 -2  5 NA
> 64:  7  0 22  1  2 -1  5 NA
> 65:  7  1 23  2  1 -1  5 NA
> 66:  7  0 24  3  1 -2  5 NA
> 67:  7  0 25  3  2 -1  5 NA
> 68:  7  1 26  4  1 -1  5 NA
> 69:  7  0 27  5  1 -1  5 -1
> 70:  7  1 28  6  1 -3  5  1
> 71:  7  1 29  6  2 -2  5  2
> 72:  7  1 30  6  3 -1  5  3
>     id TF rn rl up dn V1 PM
> ```

Finally, the intermediate result is reshaped from long to wide format.

```
res <- 
  # create a "cartesian join" of all possible changes with the rows of each group
  tmp[tmp[, seq_len(max(rl) - 1L), by = .(id)], on = .(id), allow.cartesian = TRUE][
    # copy descending counts to rows before the switch
    rl == V1, PM := dn][
      # copy ascending counts to rows after the switch
      rl == V1 + 1L, PM := up][
        # reshape from wide to long with the change count as new columns
        , dcast(.SD, id + TF + rn ~ sprintf("PM%02d", V1), value.var = "PM")][
          # join with original df to get NA rows back in
          df, on = .(rn, id, TF)][
            # omit helper column
            , -"rn"]
```

Comment: truly amazing! I've run it on my _production data_ and it works like a charm. Only hiccup is the sorting of `PM#` when `#` gets more then two digits. As I do not understand all of your code I made a temporarily fix by adding a `sprintf("%02d", ... )` so that I have `paste0("PM", sprintf("%02d",V1)`. This solution also work on my _production data_ (which generates up to `PM12`). This was obviously my mistake. I am truly grateful for your answer!

Comment: You could change/adapt this to `tidyverse` for [this Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46799063/using-tidyverse-counting-after-and-before-change-in-value-within-groups-gener) (which seems very similar to this one)

Comment: @Uwe, I'm trying to make a slight modification to your code. After having spent more then an hour on it I am asking for your help. I don’t longer want to collapse/ignore the `NA`’s. Such that case # 3, within `id == 0`, that is currently counted as `-3` is simply `NA` in `PM1`. This would also affect `PM2`, within `id == 0`, such that there is no shift at all there,a s the shift is separated by an `NA`. Could you possible point me to how I make this modification? If you like I am happy to post a new question. Thank you in advance for your kindness.

Comment: @EricFail, I'm afraid I don't have an immediate solution at hand. I need to deep dive in into my own code + I'm not sure I do fully understand what you are after. Perhaps, I need to see the expected result just to make sure that I am on the right track. So, it might be a good idea indeed to post a new question.

Comment: @Uwe, Thanks a lot! As per your suggested I've now posted [an updated version of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48306565/counting-values-after-and-before-change-in-value-within-groups-generating-new). I'll keep working to see if I can figure it out too. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I think the cartesian join is unnecessary:

```
library(data.table)
tmp <- setDT(df)[, rn := .I][!is.na(TF)][, rl := rleid(TF), by = id][
                 , `:=`(up = 1:.N, down = -.N:-1), by = .(id, rl)][
                 , `:=`(last = (rl == max(rl)) * (-down)), by = id]

up   = dcast(tmp, rn ~ rl, value.var = 'up'  , fill = 0)
down = dcast(tmp, rn ~ rl, value.var = 'down', fill = 0)
last = dcast(tmp, rn ~ rl, value.var = 'last', fill = 0)

rl.max = tmp[, max(rl)]
res = down[, 2:rl.max] + up[, 3:(rl.max+1)] + last[, 2:rl.max]

res[res == 0] = NA
res[, rn := up$rn]

setcolorder(res[df, on='rn'][,-'rn'], c('id','TF', 1:(rl.max-1)))[]
#    id TF   1   2   3   4   5
# 1:  0 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
# 2:  0  0  -3  NA  NA  NA  NA
# 3:  0 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
# 4:  0  0  -2  NA  NA  NA  NA
# 5:  0  0  -1  NA  NA  NA  NA
# 6:  0  1   1  -3  NA  NA  NA
# 7:  0  1   2  -2  NA  NA  NA
# 8:  0  1   3  -1  NA  NA  NA
# 9:  0 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#10:  0  0  NA   1  NA  NA  NA
#11:  0  0  NA   2  NA  NA  NA
#12:  1 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#13:  1  0  -3  NA  NA  NA  NA
#14:  1  0  -2  NA  NA  NA  NA
#15:  1  0  -1  NA  NA  NA  NA
#16:  1  1   1  NA  NA  NA  NA
#17:  1  1   2  NA  NA  NA  NA
#18:  1  1   3  NA  NA  NA  NA
#19:  1 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#20:  7 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
#21:  7  0  -2  NA  NA  NA  NA
#22:  7  0  -1  NA  NA  NA  NA
#23:  7  1   1  -1  NA  NA  NA
#24:  7  0  NA   1  -2  NA  NA
#25:  7  0  NA   2  -1  NA  NA
#26:  7  1  NA  NA   1  -1  NA
#27:  7  0  NA  NA  NA   1  -1
#28:  7  1  NA  NA  NA  NA   1
#29:  7  1  NA  NA  NA  NA   2
#30:  7  1  NA  NA  NA  NA   3
#    id TF   1   2   3   4   5
```

Comment: I'm trying to make a slight modification to your code. After having spent more then an hour on it I am asking for your help. I don’t longer want to collapse/ignore the `NA`’s. Such that case # 3, within `id == 0`, that is currently counted as `-3` is simply `NA` in `PM1`. This would also affect `PM2`, within `id == 0`, such that there is no shift at all there,a s the shift is separated by an `NA`. Could you possible point me to how I make this modification? If you like I am happy to post a new question. Thank you in advancef ro your kindness.

Comment: I've now posted [an updated version of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48306565/counting-values-after-and-before-change-in-value-within-groups-generating-new). Thanks.