# using tidyverse; counting after and before change in value, within groups, generating new variables for each unique shift

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, tidyverse

I am looking for a *[tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/)-solution* that can count occurrences of unique values of `TF` within groups, `id` in the data data`tbl`. When `TF` changes I want to count both forward and backwards from that point. This counting should be stored in a new variable `PM##`, so that `PM##` holds both plus and minus to each unique shift in `TF`.

This question is similar to [a question I previously asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46541843/counting-after-and-before-change-in-value-within-groups-generating-new-variabl), but here I am *specifically* looking for a solution using [`tidyverse`](http://tibble.tidyverse.org/) tools. [Uwe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3817004/uwe) provided an elegant answer to the inital question using `data.table` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46558797/1305688).

> If this question violates any SO policies please let me know and I'll be happy to reopen my initial question or append this an bounty-issue.

To illustrate my question with a *minimal working example*. I have data like this,

```
# install.packages(c("tidyverse"), dependencies = TRUE)
library(tibble)

tbl <- tibble(id = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                     1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7), 
              TF = c(NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0,
                     0, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1))
tbl
#> # A tibble: 30 x 2
#>       id    TF
#>    <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     0    NA
#>  2     0     0
#>  3     0    NA
#>  4     0     0
#>  5     0     0
#>  6     0     1
#>  7     0     1
#>  8     0     1
#>  9     0    NA
#> 10     0     0
#> # ... with 20 more rows
```

and this is what I am trying to obtain,

```
dfa <- tibble(id = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                     1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7),
              TF = c(NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0,
                     0, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1),
              PM01 = c(NA, -3, NA, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, -3, -2, -1,
                       1, 2, 3, NA, NA, -2, -1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
              PM02 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -3, -2, -1, NA, 1, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA,
                       NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -1, 1, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
              PM03 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
                       NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -2, -1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA),
              PM04 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
                       NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -1, 1, NA, NA, NA),
              PM05 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
                       NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -1, 1, 2, 3)
               )

dfa
#> # A tibble: 30 x 7
#>       id    TF  PM01  PM02  PM03  PM04  PM05
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1     0    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#>  2     0     0    -3    NA    NA    NA    NA
#>  3     0    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#>  4     0     0    -2    NA    NA    NA    NA
#>  5     0     0    -1    NA    NA    NA    NA
#>  6     0     1     1    -3    NA    NA    NA
#>  7     0     1     2    -2    NA    NA    NA
#>  8     0     1     3    -1    NA    NA    NA
#>  9     0    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
#> 10     0     0    NA     1    NA    NA    NA
#> # ... with 20 more rows
```

Comment: May I ask what you mean by "an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources"? Is `dplyr` manual such a source?

Comment: @m-dz, good question! No category really fit when I sat up the bounty, and chose _credible and/or official sources_.  As I've already gotten [one answer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46558797/1305688), as mentioned at the top, this question and the bounty is aimed specifically at a tidyverse-answer; _credible and/or official sources_ was chosen as there was no bounty category for answer from specific library or libraries.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. Some good answers already below (and I am not talking about mine)!

Answer (score 5):

Here is another *tidyverse* approach that uses `dplyr`, `tidyr` and `zoo` (used for its `na.locf` function) package:

Firstly, instead of dropping *NAs* in the `TF` column and then join back as all the other suggested approaches (including the `data.table` approach), I wrote a helper method here, that counts forward by chunks ignoring *NAs*;

```
forward_count <- function(v) {
    valid <- !is.na(v)
    valid_v <- v[valid]
    chunk_size = head(rle(valid_v)$lengths, -1)
    idx <- cumsum(chunk_size) + 1
    ones <- rep(1, length(valid_v))
    ones[idx] <- 1 - chunk_size
    v[valid] <- cumsum(ones)
    v
}
```

And it works as is required by *count after the change*:

```
v <- sample(c(NA, 0, 1), 15, replace = T)
v
# [1] NA NA NA  0  1 NA  1 NA  1  1  0  1  0  0  0
forward_count(v)
# [1] NA NA NA  1  1 NA  2 NA  3  4  1  1  1  2  3
```

*Count before the change* can be implemented by reverse the vector twice with this exact same function:

```
-rev(forward_count(rev(v)))
# [1] NA NA NA -1 -4 NA -3 NA -2 -1 -1 -1 -3 -2 -1
```

Now define the headers, count forward column as `fd`, count backward column as `bd` using `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr); library(zoo);

tidy_method <- function(df) {
    df %>% 
        group_by(id) %>% 
        mutate(
            rle_id = cumsum(diff(na.locf(c(0, TF))) != 0),   # chunk id for constant TF
            PM_fd = if_else(                 # PM count after change headers
                rle_id == head(rle_id, 1), 
                "head", sprintf('PM%02d', rle_id)
            ), 
            PM_bd = if_else(                 # shift the header up as before change headers
                rle_id == tail(rle_id, 1), 
                "tail", sprintf('PM%02d', rle_id+1)
            ), 
            fd = forward_count(TF),             # after change count
            bd = -rev(forward_count(rev(TF))),  # before change count
            rn = seq_along(id)) %>%             # row number
        gather(key, value, PM_fd, PM_bd) %>%    # align headers with the count
        mutate(count_ = if_else(key == "PM_fd", fd, bd)) %>%
        select(-key) %>% spread(value, count_) %>%    # reshaper PM column as headers
        select(id, TF, rn, matches('PM')) %>%  # drop no longer needed columns
        arrange(id, rn) %>% select(-rn)
}
```

*Timing* compared with the `data.table` method:

Define the `data.table` method as:

```
dt_method <- function(df) {
    tmp_dt <- setDT(df)[, rn := .I][!is.na(TF)][, rl := rleid(TF), by = id][
        , c("up", "dn") := .(seq_len(.N), -rev(seq_len(.N))), by = .(id, rl)][]

    res_dt <- tmp_dt[tmp_dt[, seq_len(max(rl) - 1L), by = .(id)], on = .(id), allow.cartesian = TRUE][
        rl == V1, PM := dn][rl == V1 + 1L, PM := up][
            , dcast(.SD, id + TF + rn ~ sprintf("PM%02d", V1), value.var = "PM")][
                df, on = .(rn, id, TF)][, -"rn"]
    res_dt
}
```

*Data*: A medium sized data by repeating the sample data frame 200 times:

```
df_test <- bind_rows(rep(list(df), 200))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(dt_method(df_test), tidy_method(df_test), times = 10)
#Unit: milliseconds
#                 expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#   dt_method(df_test) 2321.5852 2439.8393 2490.8583 2456.1118 2557.4423 2834.2399    10
# tidy_method(df_test)  402.3624  412.2838  437.0801  414.5655  418.6564  540.9667    10
```

Order the data.table method result by `id` and convert all column data types to numeric; the results from `data.table` approach and `tidyverse` are identical:

```
identical(
    as.data.frame(dt_method(df_test)[order(id), lapply(.SD, as.numeric)]), 
    as.data.frame(tidy_method(df_test))
)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Nice one! After a bit of fiddling (main was was to more `sprintf()` to the `tmp_dt` part) I was able to get down to ~900 ms with the data.table function (with your around 420 ms), the `dcast()` takes about 600 ms from this, not much more to do I am afraid... But will try later and post under my answer.

Comment: Very interesting to see them compared with `microbenchmark` @Uwe. This is why I started the bounty. Thanks.

Comment: @Eric Fail - Are you interested on methods only using R base? It will have a better performance.

Comment: @Marcelo, that would be very interesting! I will however have to award the current bounty to an answer that use `tidyverse` as it's the premise for the bounty. However, I think the issue of performance versus how-easy-the-code-is-to-make-sense-of is very interesting. I would very much appreciate a R base answer.

Comment: Did you test your answer on the data provided, `df`, in the working example? I get a range of errors for Duplicate identifiers when I run. I am able to run it on the `v`-sting, but not on the `df`-data-frame. Am I overlooking something?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I was using the data from your previous question, as I noticed that in this question, `dfa` and `df` are not the same. But I did realize a bug in my code, which is when the `TF` doesn't change at all for a specific `id`, then this fails. Could this happen in your real data?

Comment: I think I've fixed it with the update. Instead of giving an error, all PMs columns will be NA if `TF` doesn't change within an `id`.

Comment: I'm glad you used the data from the previous question. I made some mess creating the `tribble` here. The two `df`s should have been identical. My bad!

Comment: I updated the initial data frame here to mach the `df`, and now calling it `tbl` here. Hope that helps!

Comment: @Psidom, do think your `forward_count` could be rewritten to answer [this almost identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48306565/counting-values-after-and-before-change-in-value-within-groups-generating-new)? Also, it has an open bounty worth +100.

Answer (score 3):

#### Update with a bit optimized data.table function:

Should probably go to the old question, but maybe this will trigger some further optimization.

To keep things flowing I have played a bit with the `data.table` function and get down to about twice of the execution time of the `tidyverse` version - the bottleneck is the `dcast()` function, see the screenshot from `profvis` below:

```
dt_method <- function(dt_test) {
  tmp_dt <- dt_test[, rn := .I][!is.na(TF)][, rl := rleid(TF), by = id][
    , c("up", "dn") := .(seq_len(.N), -rev(seq_len(.N))), by = .(id, rl)][, ':='(
      rl_PM = sprintf("PM%02d", rl),
      United = paste(id, TF, rn, sep = '_')
    )]

  res_dt <- tmp_dt[, .(sprintf("PM%02d", seq_len(max(rl) - 1L)), seq_len(max(rl) - 1L)), by = .(id)] %>% 
    tmp_dt[., on = .(id), allow.cartesian = TRUE] %>%  
    .[rl == V2, PM := dn] %>%
    .[rl == V2 + 1L, PM := up] %>%
    dcast(., United ~ V1, value.var = "PM") %>%
    .[, c('id', 'TF', 'rn') := lapply(tstrsplit(United, '_'), as.numeric)] %>%
    .[dt_test, on = .(rn, id, TF)] %>% .[, -c('rn', 'United')]
  res_dt
}
```

Pipes were needed to deal with some odd errors, but I still consider them allowed even for `data.table`.

Microbenchmark results:

```
Unit: milliseconds
                 expr      min       lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
   dt_method(dt_test) 868.1491 932.8076 1048.5077 1029.9609 1078.0735 1518.0327    10
 tidy_method(df_test) 478.6824 515.5639  557.9644  565.9422  585.3143  622.1093    10
```

And `identical()` with fixed order of columns:

```
identical(
  dt_method(dt_test)[order(id), lapply(.SD, as.numeric)] %>% setcolorder(c('id', 'TF', setdiff(names(.), c('id', 'TF')))) %>% as.data.frame(),
  as.data.frame(tidy_method(df_test))
)
```

`profvis` timings:

[image]

#### Old part:

Using Uwe's answer as a base:

(Disclaimer: I am not using `dplyr` too much, treated this as an exercise for myself, so it is for sure not `dplyr`-optimal, see e.g. `dcast`.)

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

df <- tibble(id = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                    1, 1, 1, 1,7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7),
             TF = c(NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0,
                    1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1))

dfa <- tibble(id = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                     1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7),
              TF = c(NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0,
                     0, 1, 1, 1, NA, NA, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1),
              PM01 = c(NA, -3, NA, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, NA, NA, NA, NA, -3, -2, -1,
                       1, 2, 3, NA, NA, -2, -1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
              PM02 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -3, -2, -1, NA, 1, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA,
                       NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -1, 1, 2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
              PM03 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
                       NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -2, -1, 1, NA, NA, NA, NA),
              PM04 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
                       NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -1, 1, NA, NA, NA),
              PM05 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
                       NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, -1, 1, 2, 3))

tmp_dt <- setDT(df)[, rn := .I][!is.na(TF)][, rl := rleid(TF), by = id][
  , c("up", "dn") := .(seq_len(.N), -rev(seq_len(.N))), by = .(id, rl)][]

res_dt <- tmp_dt[tmp_dt[, seq_len(max(rl) - 1L), by = .(id)], on = .(id), allow.cartesian = TRUE][
  rl == V1, PM := dn][rl == V1 + 1L, PM := up][
    , dcast(.SD, id + TF + rn ~ sprintf("PM%02d", V1), value.var = "PM")][
      df, on = .(rn, id, TF)][, -"rn"]
res_dt

all.equal(res_dt, as.data.table(dfa))
```

As much tidyverse-sque as possible:

```
tmp_dplyr <- df %>%
  # create row id column (required for final join to get NA rows back in)
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  # ignore NA rows 
  filter(complete.cases(.)) %>%
  # number streaks of unique values within each group
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(rl = rleid(TF)) %>%
  # create ascending and descending counts for each streak
  # this is done once to avoid repeatedly creation of counts for each PM 
  # (slight performance gain)
  group_by(id, rl) %>%
  mutate(
    up = seq_len(n()),
    dn = -rev(seq_len(n()))
  )

res_dplyr <- tmp_dplyr %>%
  ## Replicating tmp[tmp[, seq_len(max(rl) - 1L), by = .(id)], on = .(id), allow.cartesian = TRUE]
  group_by(id) %>%
  ## Part below can for sure be optimized for code length, it's just too early now...
  transmute(rl = max(rl)) %>% # Cannot transmute id directly
  unique() %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  slice(rep(1:n(), times = rl - 1L)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  transmute(V1 = seq_len(max(rl) - 1L)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  right_join(tmp_dplyr, by = 'id') %>%
  ## End or replicating tmp[tmp[, seq_len(max(rl) - 1L), by = .(id)], on = .(id), allow.cartesian = TRUE]
  ## Copy descending counts to rows before the switch and ascending counts to rows after the switch
  mutate(
    PM = ifelse(rl == V1, dn, NA),
    PM = ifelse(rl == V1 + 1L, up, PM)
  ) %>%
  ## This is very not tidyverse-sque, but I don't get the gather/spread ...
  dcast(id + TF + rn ~ sprintf("PM%02d", V1), value.var = "PM") %>%
  full_join(df, by = c('rn', 'id', 'TF')) %>%
  select(-rn)

all.equal( ## Using data.table all.equal
  res_dplyr[do.call(order, res_dplyr),] %>% as.data.table(),
  res_dt[do.call(order, res_dt),]
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a answer without `data.table` but it was not using `dplyr`. Here is my attempt using `dplyr`:

```
        #Remove the NAs 
dfr <-  df %>% filter(!is.na(TF)) %>% 
  # group by id
  group_by(id) %>% 
  # Calculate the rle on TF for each group
  do(., mrle = rle(.$TF)) %>% mutate(Total=sum(mrle$lengths)) %>%
  # Trasform the rle result in a data.frame counting the values after and before changes
  do( {
  t<- .$mrle
  #for each length generate the columns
  res <- as.data.frame(lapply(seq_along(t$lengths[-length(t$lengths)]), function(i) {

      #before change counts
      n1 <- t$lengths[i]
      #position  the counts
      if(i==1) {
        before <- 0
      } else {
        before <- sum(t$lengths[1:i-1])
      }

      #after change conts
      n2 <- t$lengths[i+1]

      if(i == (length(t$lengths)-1))
        after  <- 0
      else
        after <- .$Total - before - n1 - n2

      # assemble the column
      c(rep(NA,before),-n1:-1,1:n2, rep(NA,after))

    } ))

  colnames(res) <- paste0("PM", 1:ncol(res))
  #preserve the id
  cbind(id=.$id,res)

 })

#Join with the original data.frame
res <-  df %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% filter(!is.na(TF)) %>% bind_cols(dfr) %>% right_join( df %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) ) %>% select(-rn, -id1)

#Verify
mapply(all.equal, dfa,res)
#  id   TF PM01 PM02 PM03 PM04 PM05 
#TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: If I run this in a clean R session (3.3.3) with `tibble_1.3.4` and `dplyr_0.7.2` I get an error that `Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("PM1", "PM0")) :  'names' attribute [2] must be the same length as the vector [0]` Do you happen to know if it is a version issue?

Comment: @EricFail -  Are you constructing the df using the code from your post? The code from your post does not create the correct df but this exposed a bug in my code when there is no changes for an ID.